# How to move course details from local database to moodle database?

Tags: moodle

I am using moodle 3.2 version . i want to move bulk of course details from local database to moodle database . Is any API or web service available? Please suggest some examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no bulk interface for doing this - the best method available would be to use backup & restore for each of the courses (assuming by 'course details' you mean the full content of the courses).

A custom plugin should be able to automate the backup & restore of multiple courses at once, but no such functionality exists in Moodle as standard.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Is it possible to use core_files_upload API to upload?. Because in moodle they are using same API for course bulk upload.

Comment: If you have a CSV file with the basic details of the courses (name, etc), but not the content, then you can use bulk course upload to create the courses for you. I am not aware of any built-in way to generate this CSV from an existing site